# does anyone use jazzer to fuzz on android binder service

Tags: android, fuzzing, android-binder

There is a java binder Service fuzzer example on source.android.com,the title of document is aidl fuzzing,I don't know how to use java API of jazzer,I got a jar file compiled from fuzzer and I don't know how tio run fuzzer